# Android MediaRecorder start failed during Outgoing call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-4.4-kitkat, mediarecorder

I am trying to make auto call recorder using a broadcast receiver  and a background service.

```
package com.mak.socialmediacallrecorder;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class BgService extends Service {

public MediaRecorder mRecorder;
private static String mFileName = null;

public BgService() {

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if(mRecorder == null) {

        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.reset();
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/aasimkhanmak.3gp";

        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        // mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        //mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();

        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        // mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);


        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Pre " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        try {
            mRecorder.start();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Start Rec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Start " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;

        }


    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if(mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Call End...Stop Rec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
}
```

This code work fine for both incoming and outgoing calls on my samsung galaxy note5 but on some other mobile which have kitkat 4.4.4 this code not work properly it only work for incoming call but when i make an outgoing call the MediaRecorder start fail.

If someone have any solution plz share with me.